# What is the intended usage of AEM Component views and partials?

Tags: sling, aem

At the following link there is a cheatsheet for Adobe Experience Manager (AEM formerly CQ).

http://activecq.com/system/assets/46/original/quick-reference.html

There is a section on the page called "Component Organization"

[image: Component Organization]

At the bottom of the list are two sections: views and partials.

My first question is, what would the x and y represent and is there some built in mechanism that already exploits this convention?

If a page included content where this component was the resourceType and the appropriate selectors were in play then those x and y JSPs would also be in play.  For instance,

```
/content/mysite/mypage.views.x.html
```

But that seems strange.  A more likely scenario is that the component is targeted through a sling include that adds or replaces selectors.

```
<sling:include resourceType="/apps/myapp/components/sample" 
               replaceSelectors="views.x" />
```

So what is the intended usage of this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe the partials folder is referring to this: https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/issues/10

The idea seems to be to break up the component into inheritable sections for ease of use and development of siblings of the parent.